# Django serializer field validation when calling serializer.is_valid

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer, requiredfieldvalidator

`class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer): state = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, required=False) def validate_state(self, state): if not isinstance(state, str): raise serializers.ValidationError("state should be a string") return state`

I want "state" to be only string format or raise exception when calling "serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)".

I dont use a model and also don't store it in a db, so i wont call update or create.

I tried this method(1) and overriding "validate" method of the serializer:
I want the exception to trigger when i call "serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)"

`def validate_state(self, state): if not isinstance(state, str): raise serializers.ValidationError("state should be a string") return state`

Comment: It will never pass to `validate_state`, one of the reasons is that the field *itself* already validates that. So you don't have to.

Comment: I was allowed to modify it to int or float, so there is no default validation

Comment: validate *how*. You don't show how you have created a `serializer`, and passed data to it.